# Call jQuery from inside Flash Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, canvas

I'm trying to call for a jQuery function when my Flash Canvas animation ends. I can't seem to figure out what code I need to add on that last keyframe in order to do that. I found something like this but it's not working:

```
this.stop();
ExternalInterface.call("javascript:start_website();");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution from browsing a few other websites. Basically at the end of my animation on the very last keyframe I added this bit of code:

```
this.animation_tracker = function() {
    start_website();
    return false; // prevent the function from being run over and over again
}
exportRoot.animation_tracker();
```

And within my website I created a jQuery function called start_website(); where I placed all the actions that I wanted to have happen once my animation was over.

Answer (score 0):

in flash canvas you are already programming in javascript (and other js libraries flash uses), so you can't use and don't need the ExternalInterface.call and such.

You can and should call straight to the javascript function:

```
this.stop();

start_website();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Tay2510 for putting the code are in the gray block which meant for code part of the comment.
I believe that was my first post in StackOverflow :)

Comment: @stefanplc , I have answered your specific question correctly. Why did you choose to ignore it?